# How to do routing for Phil Haacks area prototype for ASP.NET MVC 1.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas

I am building a simple web site for a client and this is my first time with ASP.Net Mvc.
For the production i need to use MVC 1.0 and the most efficient way to saparate Admin logic from the rest of this site is using Areas.

The fact that i couldnt use MVC 2, so i have used the Haacks area prototype and everything was ok.

I want to write a custom routing for paging results but i couldnt get it done.

```
    routes.MapAreas("{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    "Adore.Web",
                    new[] { "Admin" });

               //my custom routing
                routes.MapRoute(
                   "PagingServices",
                   "Admin/Services/{pageNumber}",
                   new { area = "Admin", controller = "Services", action = "Index" });

                routes.MapRootArea("{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    "Adore.Web",
                    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" });
```

As you see above i am trying to get this "Admin/Services/1" but couldnt figure it out.

How can i do it, thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried Phil Haack's Routing Debugger? :) http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx

That might help.

Also, it looks like the problem might be that your first route is going to match anything starting with /Admin. Try moving your custom route to the top since routes are evaluated in order.

Comment: Hi Haacked :) of course i ve tried your debugger and thanks for this great tool. Ok i will try moving the custom route to the top.
Thanks again